# How can I access my class properties from a namespace with php version 5.5.12?

Tags: php, html

I'm using WAMPSERVER 2.5 and PHP version 5.5.12 on Windows 8 PC.  I created a namespace which worked ok when I was running PHP version 5.2.12.  After upgrading to php version 5.5.12 I'm getting error message about undefined variables which I think means that the namespace is not being used.  Here's what my code looks like:

In my UploadFile.php file I have this:

```
 <?php
     namespace myNamespace;

     class UploadFile
     {

           protected $avatarUrl;


    public function getUrl()
     {

          return $this->avatarUrl;

     }


    protected function moveFile($file)
    {
           $filename = isset($this->newName) ? $this->newName : $file['name'];
    echo $file[$key];
    $success = move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $this->destination . $filename);
    if ($success) {

                    $url='http://westcoastchill.com/dc-esports/images/' . $filename;    
                    $this->avatarUrl=$url;
                        ... 
                }
                .....
 ?>
```

Then here's the html form that uses the class in the namespace where I get the error messages that states that the variable  'newUrl' is undefined and the index 'displaymax' is undifined.

```
 <?php 
 require_once 'uploads/src/myNamespace/UploadFile.php';//<------names here
 if (!isset($_SESSION['maxfiles'])) {
     $_SESSION['maxfiles'] = ini_get('max_file_uploads');
     $_SESSION['postmax'] = UploadFile::convertToBytes(ini_get('post_max_size')); 
     $_SESSION['displaymax'] =   UploadFile::convertFromBytes($_SESSION['postmax']); //<------ undifined index

 }



 $max = 50 * 1024;
 $result = array();
 if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {

 $destination = __DIR__ . '/uploads/uploaded/';
 try {
    $upload = new UploadFile($destination);
    $upload->setMaxSize($max);

    $upload->allowAllTypes();
    $upload->upload();
    $result = $upload->getMessages();
    $newUrl=$upload->getUrl();  //<----------- here's the undifined newUrl;

     } catch (Exception $e) {  
    $result[] = $e->getMessage();
     }
 }
  $error = error_get_last();
  $oldUrl=$newUrl;
  ...
 ?>
```

}
How can I access my class from a namespace with php version 5.5.12?

Thanks for any help with this!

UPDATE: Sorry I had getUrl() outside of superclass but in my actual project is in the correct place.  So I tried:

```
  \myNamespace\UploadFile::convertToBytes(ini_get('post_max_size'));...
```

but I still get the same error.  I also tried adding use:

```
  myNamespace\UploadFile and \myNamespace\UploadFile...
```

still getting the same error message.  The thing is my code worked with the using statement before I updated PHP so I'm curious why just an update would change things.

Comment: I stopped at first error, fix your code please. `public function getUrl()` is declared outside of its supposed class. There likely is more to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the configuration of the php.ini file.  After researching more I tried turning off 'display_errors=Off in the php.ini file and the code the code ran using the namespace and everything.  Conclusion:  the php.ini file of the new installation different settings.  I'll explore the settings more but my problem was solved by turning off error displaying.  Obviously this is not a desired option so I'll toggle on and off as I go forward and read up on other parameters in the file that may help me.

Answer (score 0):

`UploadFile` class is within the namespace `myNamespace`, so to reference the class from outside of `myNamespace`, you would need to use `\myNamespace\UploadFile`.

If you are already in the global namespace, you don't need the leading slash, but I think it's good practice to always use the leading slash, since the leading slash refers to the global namespace.

Ex:

```
$_SESSION['postmax'] = \myNamespace\UploadFile::convertToBytes(ini_get('post_max_size'));
```

and

```
$upload = new \myNamespace\UploadFile($destination);
```

Comment: I added the \myNamespace\UploadFile($destination); but still get the error.